# Convert yymmddhhmm date/time string to PHP timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

I have a string that is a 10 digit date/time representation in the format of yymmddhhmm, e.g:

1304282240

is the 28th of April, 2013 22:40 (28/04/13 in the DD/MM/YY format)

I need to convert this into a valid PHP timestamp but I'm getting stuck using the Date and strtotime functions, and not sure if that is the best approach in any case.

Update: I've added these lines to my code:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('ymdHi', '1304282240');
echo $date->format('m/d/Y h:i:s A');
```

appears to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('ymdHi', '1304282240');
```

Comment: Thanks @DeeDee - see my additional comments above, I can't get it to echo out the timestamp. Any ideas?

Comment: I think I found my problem, this appears to work: echo $date->format('m/d/Y h:i:s A');

Comment: Awesome, glad you found it!